# composing small matrices to a large matrix inside a for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

Suppose we have a function that has some output, including some numbers and matrices as

```
[A,a,B,n,m] = func(file)
```

The `file` as input differs each time and `func` will read it inside a loop `for`.
Matrix `B` has always two columns with variable rows that depends on the input file and computation inside `func`. 
now I would like to save these matrices `B` each time in the output. The number of iteration is fix, say 10.

`for` loop is something like this

```
for i=1:10
    ..... %// here reads the name of the input file which differs each iteration
    [A,a,B,n,m] = func(file)
    .....
end
```

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cell array:

```
B_all = cell(1, 10);
for i=1:10
        % here reads the name of the input file which differs each iteration

        [A,a,B,n,m] = func(file);
        B_all{i} = B;

        % Continue calculation here
end;
```

If you want to merge them in the end (i.e. to have a single matrix with 2 columns):

```
B_merged = vertcat(B_all{:});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one comment about merging. I know it is not possible to merge them horizontal while the number of rows are not identical. But is it possible that we choose the largest row and put for other small rows symbol '-'?

Comment: @Royeh It is possible to extend them to the largest number of rows. But before trying to put '-' into your newly created rows, are you sure that your `B` is a `char` matrix? or is it a numeric matrix?

Comment: @CST_Link Of course it is numeric and then it may be fine to put zero instead.

Comment: @Royeh. Also consider `NaN` for your empty value placeholders.